# Replacing TBB parallel_for with OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, tbb, parallel.for

I'm trying to come up with an equivalent replacement of an Intel TBB `parallel_for` loop that uses a `tbb::blocked_range` using OpenMP. Digging around online, I've only managed to find mention of one other person doing something similar; a patch submitted to the Open Cascade project, wherein the TBB loop appeared as so (but did not use a tbb::blocked_range):

```
tbb::parallel_for_each (aFaces.begin(), aFaces.end(), *this);
```

and the OpenMP equivalent was:

```
int i, n = aFaces.size();
#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    Process (aFaces[i]);
```

Here is TBB loop I'm trying to replace:

```
tbb::parallel_for( tbb::blocked_range<size_t>( 0, targetList.size() ), DoStuff( targetList, data, vec, ptr ) );
```

It uses the `DoStuff` class to carry out the work:

```
class DoStuff
{
private:
    List& targetList;
    Data* data;
    vector<things>& vec;
    Worker* ptr;

public:
    DoIdentifyTargets( List& pass_targetList, 
                       Data* pass_data, 
                       vector<things>& pass_vec, 
                       Worker* pass_worker) 
        : targetList(pass_targetList), data(pass_data), vecs(pass_vec), ptr(pass_worker)
    {
    }

    void operator() ( const tbb::blocked_range<size_t> range ) const
    {
        for ( size_t idx = range.begin(); idx != range.end(); ++idx )
        {
            ptr->PerformWork(&targetList[idx], data->getData(), &Vec);
        }
    }
};
```

My understanding [based on this reference](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/range_concept/blocked_range_cls.htm) is that TBB will divide the blocked range into smaller subsets and give each thread one of the ranges to loop through. Since each thread will get its own `DoStuff` class, which has a bunch of references and pointers, meaning the threads are essentially sharing those resources.

Here's what I've come up with as an equivalent replacement in OpenMP:

```
int index = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(index)
for (index = 0; index < targetList.size(); ++index)
{
    ptr->PerformWork(&targetList[index], data->getData(), &Vec);
}
```

Because of circumstances outside of my control (this is merely one component in a much larger system that spans +5 computers) stepping through the code with a debugger to see exactly what's happening is... Unlikely. I'm working on getting remote debugging going, but it's not looking very promising. All I know for sure is that the above OpenMP code is somehow doing something differently than TBB was, and expected results after calling PerformWork for each index are not obtained.

Given the information above, does anyone have any ideas on why the OpenMP and TBB code are not functionally equivalent?

Comment: How much have you abstracted away the original code in your example?  a `tbb::blocked_range` works with the range reversed but `for` wouldn't.

Comment: And another possibility is that your change in type from `size_t` to `int` is actually a problem if you have a huge number of elements.

Comment: All I've done to the code is changed the class and variable names to be more generic, aside from that it's the same. The expected number of elements is only around 100-500, and OpenMP requires the use of a signed int for an index variable, so there aren't a lot of options even if that was the problem. If I get remote debugging working I'll be sure to check the number of elements, but I highly doubt it's enough to overflow the signed int.

Comment: have you tried running the loop in serial and backwards as suggested by Ben? Also, you shouldn't have to make idx private, capture the length before the loop and use it in the comparison, but declare idx as normal in your loop. (from my phone, excuse typos)

Comment: @Rick, why should capturing the length before the loop matter?

Comment: it shouldn't make a difference, perhaps making index private it was always its initial value. it's been awhile since I've read the spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Ben and Rick's advice, I tested the following loop without the omp pragma (serially) and obtained my expected results (very slowly). After adding the pragma back in, the parallel code also performs as expected. Looks like the problem was either in declaring the index as private outside of the loop, or declaring numTargets as private inside the loop. Or both.

```
    int numTargets = targetList.size();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int index = 0; index < numTargets; ++index)
    {
        ptr->PerformWork(&targetList[index], data->getData(), &vec);
    }
```

Comment: `index` will be private either way so you don't need to explicitly declare it private (but it should not hurt).  It's one of the "features" of OpenMP to accomodate ansi C which does not allow mixed declarations.  Normally everything outside of the parallel block is shared but this is the exception to the rule.  So that could not have been your problem.  If there was a problem it could have to been in calling `targetList.size()` but I don't know why.